# вывести часть последовательности 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 на python 3

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Пытаюсь решить задачу:

> Напишите программу, которая выводит часть последовательности 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 ... (число повторяется столько раз, чему равно). На вход программе передаётся положительное целое число n — столько элементов последовательности должна отобразить программа. На выходе ожидается последовательность чисел, записанных через пробел в одну строку.

Например, если n = 7, то программа должна вывести 1 2 2 3 3 3 4.

Sample Input:
7

Sample Output:
1 2 2 3 3 3 4

Вот что получается, проблема в том что на больших числах не работает.

```
a=int(input())
b=''
for i in range(a+1):
    b = b + (str(i) + ' ')*i
print(b[0:a*2])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что в последнем операторе Вы обрезаете результирующую строку, предполагая, что содержащиеся в ней числа имеют длину в один символ. Но это, естественно, не так. Чтобы избежать этой ошибки, можно, например, использовать списки:

```
v = []

for i in range(1, n+1):
    v += [str(i)] * i

print(" ".join(v[:n]))
```

Используя генераторы списков, всё это можно записать в одну строку:

```
print(" ".join([str(i) for i in range(1, n+1) for j in range(i)][:n]))
```

Правда, весь вышеприведённый код неэффективный, поскольку генерирует существенно больше данных, чем нужно для вывода на экран.

А вот более эффективный код, который генерирует ровно столько данных, сколько нужно:

```
v = []

for i in range(1, n+1):
    c = min(n, i)
    n = n - c
    v += [str(i)] * c
    if n <= 0:
        break

print(" ".join(v))
```

Не теряя эффективности, но выигрывая в понятности, можно немножко поиграть с *генераторами* (не путать с *генераторами списков*!):

```
def generator(m):
    c = 0
    for i in range(1, m+1):
        for j in range(i):
            c += 1
            if c > m:
                return
            yield str(i)

print(" ".join(generator(n)))
```

Comment: можно `print(*args)` использовать вместо `print(" ".join(map(str, args)))`.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы напечатать `n` чисел из последовательности, удобно [`itertools` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import itertools

def generate():
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        yield from [str(i)] * i 

n = int(input('Enter n: '))
print(*itertools.islice(generate(), n))
```

Пример:

```
Enter n: 7
1 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

Comment: Тогда уже использовать и `itertools.repeat(str(i), i)` вместо `[str(i)] * i`

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev: хорошее предложение, но `repeat()` не является более читаемым для меня, хотя для поддержки больших `n` его стоит использовать.

Answer (score 3):

```
s,a = [],int(input())
for i in range(1,a+1):
    s.extend([i]*i)
print(*s[:a])
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант решения через while:

```
n = int(input('Enter number:'))
count1 = 1
count2 = 0
num_print = ()
globul_count = 0
while globul_count != n: 
    num_print = count1
    while count2 < count1:
        count2 += 1
        print(num_print, end=' ')
        globul_count += 1
        if globul_count == n :
            break
        continue
    count1 += 1
    count2 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for i in range(1, n +1):
    c = min(i,n)
    n = n - c
    a += [i] * c
    if n <= 0:
        break
print(*a)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Ваш ответ ничем не отличается от того, что уже был принят.

Answer (score 1):

Не самый короткий, но мне кажется, что довольно простой для понимания:

```
a = int(input())
n = 1
q = ''
w = 1
e = 1
while n <= a:
    if w > e:
        e += 1
        w = 1
    q += str(e) + ' '
    w += 1
    n += 1
print(q)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input())

result = [i for i in range(1, n+1) for __ in range(i)][:n]
[print(i, end=" ") for i in result]
```