# Как обрезать распакованный список списков до определенной длины?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input())
lst = []

for i in range(1, n):
    p = [i]*i
    lst.append(p)
for i in lst:
    print(*i, end=" ")
```

В данной программе выводится последовательность чисел, которые повторяются столько раз сколько равны. Нужно обрезать ее до числа n.
Пример, если n = 6, то последовательность должна выводиться: 1 2 2 3 3 3
Но у меня никак не выходит обрезать до этого числа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
lst = []
i = 1 # для создания группы из i элементов, равных i

while len(lst) < n:
    lst.extend([i] * i)
    i += 1

print(lst[:n])
```

Answer (score 2):

Тут два вопроса: как генерировать нужную вам последовательность чисел? Как из этой последовательности выделить кусок нужной длины?

```
import itertools


# последовательность 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 ...
def gen():
    for i in itertools.count(start=1):
        yield from itertools.repeat(i, i)


# отрезаем первые n членов
n = int(input())
print(*itertools.islice(gen(), n))
```

Если вы не хотите пользоваться `itertools`, то всё можно сделать вручную:

```
def gen():
    j = 1
    while True:
        for _ in range(j):
            yield j
        j += 1


def slice(seq, n):
    i = 0
    for j in seq: 
        if i == n:
            break
        yield j
        i += 1


n = int(input())
print(*slice(gen(), n))
```

Или можно всё собрать в кучу:

```
def gen(n):
    i = 0
    j = 1
    while True:
        for _ in range(j):
            if i == n:
                return
            yield j
            i += 1
        j += 1


n = int(input())
print(*gen(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Такое подойдет? Немного не то, но результат в принципе подходит.

```
n = int(input())
lst = []

for i in range(1, n):
    p = [i] * i
    lst.extend(p)

lst = lst[:n]
print(lst)
```

А вообще уже был похожий вопрос. Возможно вам подойдет даже больше чем моя версия.
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477678/вывести-часть-последовательности-1-2-2-3-3-3-4-4-4-4-5-5-5-5-5-на-python-3?rq=1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477678/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-1-2-2-3-3-3-4-4-4-4-5-5-5-5-5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-3?rq=1)

Comment: да я видела тот вопрос, только мой код сильно отличается, подумала, что быть может есть вариант решить проблему именно с моим вариантом